# Vuforia Smart Terrain Start/Stop/Reset

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm getting confused by Vuforia's Smart Terrain. [Here](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/How-To-Customize-a-Smart-Terrain-Scene) you can see some methods which allow you to customize your Smart Terrain. `Start()` and `Stop()` methods are inherited from Tracker but `Reset()`, `StartMeshUpdates()`, `StopMeshUpdates()` aren't available. There shown in the link above but when I open the declaration of SmartTerrainTracker in Monodevelop, those methods are missing? What could be wrong? I can't `Reset()` my SmartTerrain because th method is given as undefined.

Do you have any ideas what the problem could be and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I have a simple C# script, attached to the SmartTerrain Prefab (the one, created when you enable the SmartTerrain on your ImageTarget). MonoBehaviour is extended in this class and the Vuforia library is used - `using Vuforia;`

SmartTerrainTracker instance is get like in the example provided in the reference above - `this.mTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<SmartTerrainTracker>();`

Still no such methods like StartMeshUpdates() and Reset() are available.

Comment: Please add your code so we can see if anything's missing, or narrow down on the problem.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I provided more information. Please see my edits.

Comment: Without your code, we cannot help you.